# JSON structure in Python Couch Db

Tags: python, couchdb

Hai guys I want to post data to my CouchDB using API.

this is the created document that I post

```
{
   "_id": "file1_benchmark",
   "_rev": "1-8efcf01444c3e47532445f81bdbe02b5",
   "id_stn": "104",
   "no_stn": "S 0221",

}
```

and this is my structure in Model.

```
class Data(Document):
    _id = TextField(),
    id_stn = DictField(),
    no_stn = DictField()

     ))
```

But the result that I want for my Document is like this:

```
{
       "_id": "file1_benchmark",
       "_rev": "1-8efcf01444c3e47532445f81bdbe02b5",
       {
       "id_stn": "104",
       "no_stn": "S 0221",
       },
       {
       "id_stn": "105",
       "no_stn": "S 0222",
       }

    }
```

What is the correct way to change my Model?

Comment: it's not exactly a json... you need a property name for each of the `{"id_stn":...}` sub nodes. Am I correct?

Comment: @Shai Yes.. I need property for sub nodes